# Proof that winding number for certain vectorfield is an integer for closed $C^1$ curve

Tags: multivariable-calculus, differential-geometry, vector-analysis, differential-forms

Say I have the following vector field: $$\omega : \mathbb{R^2} \backslash \{0\} \to \mathbb{(R^2)}  
   ,(x,y) \mapsto (\frac{-y}{x^2+y^2}, \frac{x}{x^2+y^2}). $$

I want to show that the winding number $n(c,0) = \frac{1}{2\pi} \int_c \omega $ around 0 for a smooth closed curve $c$  is an integer.

I know that my vector field is not conservative even though it fulfills $$\partial_{y}\omega_1 = \partial_{x}\omega_2.$$ I unsure how to proceed, but I feel like I have to use some special properties of the vector field, like the fact that it is the derivative of the Argument function, or the fact that it is the standard example of a closed but non-exact $1$-Form.

Further question: If I let $\omega$ be defined on an open, connected domain $D$ such that $\omega$ is exact on $D$, I want to show that $n(c,0) = \frac{1}{2\pi} \int_c \omega =0. $

Comment: Parametrize a circle and calculate.

Comment: But can I just change the parameterization to a circle? I thought I could only do that if my $1$ form has an antiderivative, i.e. is exact.

Comment: Can you use the fact, that a circle centered in the origin is homotopic to an smooth closed curve around the origin?

Comment: I haven't taken a proper topology class yet, so believe I should search for a more "elementary" proof.

Comment: @JamesS.Cook This does not answer the question, because it's asked more general for a smooth closed curve

Comment: The fact that it's (locally) the derivative of the argument function is probably the most elementary way to proceed, since it means you can ignore the radial coordinate and reduce to a one-dimensional problem.

Comment: @Fakemistake fair enough, but, we can find a circle sufficiently small that it fits inside the closed curve. Then a deformation argument can be used to show that the integral around the circle matches the integral around the loop. Notice regions between this small circle and the loop will be simply connected and the form is exact on any region which does not enclose the origin.

Comment: @JamesS.Cook Yes, and you used a topology argument

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments, the idiomatic way to do this is via deformation: any closed curve in the punctured plane is homotopic to $t \mapsto (\cos(kt),\sin(kt))$ for some integer $k$; so it suffices to compute the integrals on these coverings of the circle and then use the fact that the integral of a closed form is homotopy invariant. Since you said you don't want to use topological tools, though, here's an elementary approach requiring nothing more than multivariable calculus.

Let $\gamma : [0,1] \to \mathbb R^2 \setminus\{0\}$ be a smooth parametrization of $c$. Since the curve is closed, we know $\gamma(0) = \gamma(1)$.

Define the function $\phi(t) = \mathrm{Arg}(\gamma(0)) + \int_0^t \omega(\gamma(t)) \cdot \gamma'(t) dt$ so that $\int_c \omega = \phi(1) - \phi(0)$. The intuition here is that since $\omega = d \mathrm Arg$ locally, $\phi$ should give the argument of $\gamma$ (up to a multiple of $2 \pi$), and thus $\phi(1) - \phi(0)$ must be a multiple of $2\pi$ in order for the curve to close up.

In order to make this rigorous, I would proceed in two steps:

- Prove that $\gamma(t) = |\gamma(t)|(\cos \phi(t), \sin\phi(t))$ using calculus. (They agree at $t=0$ by definition, so it suffices to show their derivatives agree.)
- Thus prove that $\gamma(0) = \gamma(1)$ implies $\phi(1) = \phi(0) + 2 \pi n$ for some integer $n$.

For your further question, just apply the fundamental theorem of calculus and use the fact that the endpoints join up.